# securing access to url and rootScope undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("myApp",
        ["common.services",
            "$rootScope",
            "ui.router",
            "ui.mask",
            "userService",          
            "ui.bootstrap"]);        

    app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider","$rootScope",
            function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $rootScope) {
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

                $stateProvider
                    .state("index", {
                        url: "/",
                        templateUrl: "app/index.html",
                    })
                    // Home page /* SECURED */
                    .state("home", {
                        url: "/home",
                        templateUrl: "app/home/home.html",
                        controller: "HomeController as vm",
                        data: {
                            requiresLogin: true
                        }
                    })
                     // Login
                    .state("login", {
                        url: "/login",
                        templateUrl: "app/login/login.html",
                        controller: "LoginController as vm"
                    })

            }]
    );
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (e, to, userService) {
          if (to.data && to.data.requiresLogin) {
            if (!userService.user.loggedIn()) {
              //token not found/not valid
              e.preventDefault();
              $location.path('/login');
            }
          }
        });
}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post what the problem is, but I assume it is that nothing works. If so here is obvious problem with your code: you are trying use `$rootScope` as module dependency to application module.

Correct module definition must be:

```
angular.module("myApp", [
     "common.services",
     "ui.router",
     "ui.mask",
     "userService",          
     "ui.bootstrap"
])
```

I removed `"$rootScope"` from the list.

**UPD**. Closer look revealed another problem. You can't inject $rootScope into config block. Move it to the run:

```
app
  .config([...])
  .run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on(...);
  }];
```

Comment: I removed $rootScope from the list and everything else remains as it was, it is injected into config object still. So my problem still remains. Thanks for your time. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you cant inject services (rootScope is service) in config only provides
but you can do it in app.run 
Here's the calling order:

1. app.config() //only provides can be injected
2. app.run()
3. directive's compile functions (if they are found in the dom)
4. app.controller()
5. directive's link functions (again, if found)

   ```
   app.run(["$stateProvider","$rootScope","userService",
     function($stateProvider,$rootScope,userService){
       $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
       if (toState.data && toState.data.requiresLogin) {
       if (!userService.user.loggedIn()) {
           //token not found/not valid
           e.preventDefault();
           $location.path('/login');
         }
       }
     });  
   }]);
   ```